# Using WPDB class

Tags: wpdb

I want to use the `wpdb` class on my external page not associated with wordpress.

I tried to include the following on the php file:

```
// include wordpress functions
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
require_wp_db();
global $wpdb;
```

Now I made a query using `$wpdb->query`

```
$product_info_query = $wpdb->query("select p.products_id, p.products_type, p.img_display, p.products_sku, pd.products_name, pd.products_description, p.products_model, p.products_quantity, p.products_image, pd.products_url, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_date_added, p.products_last_modified, p.products_date_available, p.manufacturers_id, gp.likes from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd, " . TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS . " gp where p.products_status = '1' and p.products_id = '" . (int)$_GET['products_id'] . "' and pd.products_id = p.products_id and gp.products_id = p.products_id and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'");
$product_info = mysql_fetch_array($product_info_query);
```

However, its not working. It returned a warning:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

What seems to be the problem? How to fix this and probably use `wpdb` class correctly on running queries outside wordpress?

Comment: Have you tried doing a simple query like `SELECT * FROM sometablename` to see if it's actually working? Btw: You're missing all the funkyness of the `$wpdb` class like `prepare()`...

Comment: YES.. I tried the query using native `mysql_query()` and its working.. I also tried adding `$wpdb->prepare()` and the problem persists.

Comment: I meant if a simply query works with `$wpdb`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) with [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). They are not compatible. You need to use [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) methods, plus PHP functions like `while`, `foreach`, and `for`. `wpdb` does not return the references that PHP's mysql functions use. It returns an object, and array, or sometimes a string.

In your case, though, the database part is done. You just want to `foreach` over the result set.

```
foreach ($products as $op) {
    // do stuff
}
```